# "from my end" vs "from my side"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

Today my manager finished his speech with:

> "I'm done from my end. If you have anything from your end, please let me know."

My question is, wouldn't it be appropriate to use `from my/your side` than `my/your end` especially in a formal context like a meeting?

Answer (score 3):

"I'm done" in itself is quite an informal expression, so I don't think the real issue here is whether "from my end/side" is formal or informal. There is a difference between *formal* and *professional*, and it is the latter that you need to consider with choice of language in work meetings. Many modern workplaces have adopted a casual or informal approach to speech and dress, but they would still expect a level of *professionalism* from employees in their approach to work.

"From my end" and "from my side" are pretty much identical in meaning. If your boss said "*I'm done from my end*" then it seems reasonable to assume you could use the same or similar expressions, but "my end/side" is referring to your area of responsibility, so to me, the important factor in saying this would be that you were not avoiding something that is your responsibilty.